# SharePoint How To display content type form dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts

I have an asp drop down list in a WebPart that contain list of document Library content types.

when i choose a content type i need to display the fields of these content type to create new item from it

How i can use SharePoint Controls here like ListFieldIterator or DocumentLibraryFiels or other controls if exist ?

Thank you in advance.